# Эффект для кнопки

Tags: css, bootstrap

Есть кнопка, сделанная через классы `bootstrap`. Единственное, что изменено: `background:transparent`.

Кто знает, как сделать, чтобы, допустим, с интервалом в секунд 5 по ней справа налево пробегали искорки... белые. Дабы получилось, что кнопка мерцает и привлекает внимание. Смотрел эффекты для кнопок, но все какие-то невзрачные, а хочется, чтобы внимание пользователя постоянно акцентировалось на ней.

Comment: Не представляю, что вы имеете ввиду под _искорками_, и не будут ли предложенные варианты _невзрачными_? Конкретизируйте вопрос. Приложите пример.

Comment: мерцала чтобы кнопка.Куда уж конкретнее.А пример какой можно приложить?Если бы мне попалось что-то подобное, то я бы наверное посмотрел как реализовано..

Comment: пример - нарисовать можно. Чтобы было понятно, что за _искорки_, какой формы, размера

Comment: Вот справа от окна комментария есть кнопка "комментировать". Пусть будет такая же кнопка.Только фон прозрачный.А объяснить слова "мерцала"  даже не понимаю как, если сразу не ясно о чем речь.На тему рисовать - это мне нужно gifку создать ради того чтобы объяснить???

Comment: вы так объясняете, как-будто дали ссылку на сайт или макет

Comment: Сергей в ответе чуть ниже сразу понял о чем я.Но и тебе спасибо что откликнулся.Удачного дня

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Искорки и время уже сами проставите, но вот подобный эффект

```css
@keyframes shine {
 from {
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
 }

 50% {
  opacity: 1;
 }

 to {
  opacity: 0;
  left: 100%;
 }
}

.btn {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.btn:after {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 width: 0;
 height: 86%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 7%;
 left: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 background-color: red;
 box-shadow: 0 0 25px 5px red;
 transform: skewX(-20deg);
}

.btn:hover {
 transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.btn:hover:after {
 animation: shine 0.5s 0s linear;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Send message</button>
```

Comment: Все, спасибо.Это примерно то что нужно.Осталось только реализовать анимацию не на ховере, а в обычном состоянии и сделать ее инфинити.Спасибо бро.+1 к ауре добра!Удачного дня.